# Visual Studio stopped showing documentation for Framework (System) classes

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 Community and it stopped showing documentation for Framework classes (when hovering over class/method/property etc. or typing F12 over it). It still shows documentation for project classes (comment documentation). When typing F12 (Go to definition) on System classes, metadata shows no documentation comments at all.

I've already tried:

- restarting Visual Studio
- starting Visual Studio in safe mode
- switching to another solution

but to no avail.

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml doesn't show any relevant error.

I've searched a lot about it but didn't find any tip or clue.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and exactly the same problem. I even tried to reinstall framework documentation and restart after that. VS just refuses to show documentation. It shows however my own documentation from XML comments.

Comment: I've recently installed VS 2015 Community and now VS 2013 is showing documentation again...

Comment: There is a faster way: install the latest NET Framework Development Pack (google it), optionally go into Help / Add help content and add the documentation for the framework again. It is important to install the currently used version, I installed 4.6.2 for my 2015.